# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin manual trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, continuous-delivery

I am testing a simple pipeline

Job1 -> Job2

But inside Job1 I configured a post-build action Build other project (manual step).

When I start the pipeline the Job1 runs ok and stop. But when I try to run manually the Job2 nothing happens. I see a load bar inside the Job2 but when the page refresh the job not run.

Anyone?

Comment: If jobs are configured using Pipeline DSL could you enclose both configurations?

Comment: It is using Pipeline Views Plugin